# How to fix page responsive?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I really have an annoying problem. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_equal_height_media This is the exact thing I use on my site but the content is different. So the problem I have is that the columns will not move if I reduce the browser size. 
And the right column will move onto the sidebar, however, I don't want the sidebar to be fixed at all sizes.
I use the Wordpress plugin, Wpbakery. And my theme is Phlox.
This is my site https://sijour.com/offer/ I thought it is better to share the link, instead of the screenshots.

(If I copy the same thing from w3school to the raw html in wpbakery, still columns will overlap with sidebar and if the browser is smaller than 600px the 1st column will be visible)

I tried something, I created a new page from dashboard then I chose Html I pasted everything in there, it was good, but still, when I checked the preview it doesn't work properly.

Comment: i wanted to help but the whole thing is just wrong. I really suggest you to use https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Is the problem that when you resize the window to be small, but still over 600px wide, the third column overlaps with the side-bar?

Comment: Yes it overlaps with sidebar
the columns are supposed to rearranged just like in w3school example.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your current CSS:

```
.col-container .col {
    float: left;
}
```